# Firebase Rules - validating with uid or uid.child on read

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In my project, I have permitted to user create an account by email or by phoneNumber. When user login at first time, I get complementary data such as email (when login by phoneNumber) and phoneNumber(when login by email) and update user data through a cloud function, to keep both information updated in auth() object.

Now I would like to avoid user to create 2 accounts. So, to do this I'm saving data on my database and then check if a new user by phoneNumber (for example) already has an account with his informed email.

This is OK, but I have a security issue to solve: to do this I needed to able user to read all childs from "login" key, and I would like to permit only read to his own uid and any other that has a child key called 'email_principal' as the same of his informed email.

Here's my new database rules, that is not working:

```
"login": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "auth.uid === $uid || auth.token.admin === true || auth.token.email === data.child('email_principal').val()",
    ".write": "auth.uid === $uid || auth.token.admin === true",
  }      
},
```

I already tried to do like this (is not working too):

```
"login": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "auth.uid === $uid || auth.token.admin === true || auth.token.email === root.child('email_principal/'+$uid+'/email_principal').child.val()",
    ".write": "auth.uid === $uid || auth.token.admin === true",
  }      
},
```

Here's my database structure:

[image]

And, I'm trying to retrieve data like above and getting "Error: permission_denied at /login: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data"

```
let ref = this.database.ref('login')
return ref.orderByChild('email_principal').equalTo(newEmail).once('value')
.then((snapshot) => {
})
```

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow the user to query on `/login`, they'll need read permission at `/login`. Your rule defines read permission on `/login/$uid`. So no matter what that rule allows, reads on `/login` will be rejected.

I think you're look to [securely query the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules).

```
"login": {
  ".read": "query.orderByChild == 'email_principal' &&
            query.equalTo == auth.token.email" 
}
```

This allows the user to read `/login` **if** they have the query that is specified in the rules.